# DataFrame source csv is overwritten when manipulating df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

I'm playing with `DataFrames` and I read some data from a `*.csv`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(report_csv_path)
```

> ```
> ,duration,end,start
> 0,19800000,2019-03-28T17:00:00+02:00,2019-03-28T11:30:00+02:00
> 1,12600000,2019-03-28T10:00:00+02:00,2019-03-28T06:30:00+02:00
> 2,3600000,2019-03-27T21:00:00+02:00,2019-03-27T20:00:00+02:00
> ```

then I do things that don't work like trying to parse and set values etc and the next time I want to do something else the data is gone and the `csv` contains only a single column that I just tried to modify e.g. (this fails because I still haven't figure it out but it'd be great if it didn't modify the source)

```
parse_timestamp = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

for (i, row) in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, "start"] = parse_timestamp(row["start"])
```

Is it possible that `df` is still connected to the file? If so, how can I break this connection so that it doesn't destroy my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer but too long for a comment.

No, `read_csv` closes file handler when it's done, so no connection there.

Second, you don't need `iterrows`, which is horribly slow, to convert datetime, you can do:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
```

and pandas will detect (most) of common datetime format. You can even integrate that process into `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(report_csv_path, parse_dates=['start'])
```

Comment: This issue is super weird. As soon as I manipulate any _cell_ in the `DataFrame` I instatly see this change in `VSCode` where I have that file open o_O, the only difference is that the _new_ `csv` doesn't have the index column anymore.

Comment: That is indeed very weird. Are you also running python scripts inside VSCode?

Comment: nope, I use PyCharm pro and it's happening both with and without attached debugger... maybe it's PyCharm's issue...

Comment: ok, it's definitely PyCharm because when I run the script form the command-line the `csv` remains unchanged